# Import CSV data into Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, opencsv, kaggle

When trying to use the `IMPORTDATA` function for this file:

https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset#players_20.csv

An unexpected error occurs that says it is impossible to import data into the spreadsheet. Is there any other way that I can bring this data to my spreadsheet?

This data would be very important to the work I'm doing. It would save me from almost 3 months of work to be able to type and copy everything and then filtering according to my need.

It would be very important to be able to import at least the simple info of all players, but do not necessarily have to import all columns of info from each player. The amount of columns can import is already perfect.

I would be grateful if there was any way.

Comment: Have you tried `Utilities.parseCsv()`?

Comment: Looks like [the link](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset#players_20.csv) that you've shared is technically an HTML page and not actually a CSV. When I tried downloading the sheet from Kaggle directly through other buttons, it spit up a zip file instead. Can you perhaps find a direct `csv` link that actually consists of the data file? We should be able to help import that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to download a CSV file of `players_20.csv` from `https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset` and put the CSV data to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, the CSV data cannot be directly downloaded from the URL of `https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset#players_20.csv`. In order to download the CSV file, it is required to login to kaggle. As other pattern, you can also download it using API. In this answer, in order to download the CSV file, I used Kaggle's public API.

### Usage:

#### 1. Retrieve token file:

Before you use the script, please register an account to `https://www.kaggle.com`, and retrieve the token file. About how to retrieve the token file, you can see [the official document](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api#authentication).

> In order to use the Kaggle’s public API, you must first authenticate using an API token. From the site header, click on your user profile picture, then on “My Account” from the dropdown menu. This will take you to your account settings at https://www.kaggle.com/account. Scroll down to the section of the page labelled API:
>
> To create a new token, click on the “Create New API Token” button. This will download a fresh authentication token onto your machine.

In this script, the token object in the downloaded token file is used.

#### 2. Run script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. And please set the variavles of `csvFilename`, `path` and `tokenObject`. In your case, I have already set `csvFilename` and `path`. So please set only your token object.

```
function myFunction() {
  var csvFilename = "players_20.csv"; // Please set the CSV filename.
  var path = "stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset"; // Please set the path.
  var tokenObject = {"username":"###","key":"###"}; // <--- Please set the token object.
  
  var baseUrl = "https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/";
  var url = baseUrl + path;
  var params = {headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(tokenObject.username + ':' + tokenObject.key)}};
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  var csvBlob = Utilities.unzip(blob).filter(function(b) {return b.getName() == csvFilename});
  if (csvBlob.length == 1) {
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvBlob[0].getDataAsString());
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  } else {
    throw new Error("CSV file of " + csvFilename + " was not found.");
  }
}
```

Flow:

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. When the script is run, the kaggle command of `kaggle datasets download -d stefanoleone992/fifa-20-complete-player-dataset` is run with Google Apps Script. By this, the ZIP file is downloaded.
2. Retrieve the CSV file of `csvFilename` from the downloaded ZIP file.
3. Parse the CSV data from the CSV file.
4. Put the CSV data to the active sheet.

   - In this script, all data is processed with the blob. So the file is not created.

### Note:

- It seems that the CSV data is large. So please wait until the script is finished.

  - In my environment, I spent for about 150 seconds until the CSV data is put to the Spreadsheet.
  - The CSV data of `players_20.csv` has 18279 rows and 104 columns.
- If an error occurs at `Utilities.unzip(blob)`, please test to modify from `var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob()` to `var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setContentTypeFromExtension()`.

### References:

- [Authentication of Kaggle's public API](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api#authentication)
- [kaggle-api](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added 1:

If you want to select the columns you want to put, please modify above sample script as follows.

#### From:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvBlob[0].getDataAsString());
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

#### To:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvBlob[0].getDataAsString());
var needColumns = [1, 2, 3];
csvData = csvData.map(function(row) {return needColumns.map(function(col) {return row[col]})});
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

- In above modification, as the test case, the columns of 1, 2 and 3 are put to the Spreadsheet.

### Added 2:

From [the result of benchmark for putting CSV data to Spreadsheet](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7), for example, how about using Sheets API for putting CSV data? For this, please modify above sample script as follows. Before you run the script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### From:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvBlob[0].getDataAsString());
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

#### To:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {data: csvBlob[0].getDataAsString(), coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}, delimiter: ","}}]};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
```

- In this case, I spent for about 50 seconds until the CSV data is put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [Benchmark: Importing CSV Data to Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/030203c695b308606041587e6da269e7)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

Comment: Now I can understand the differential to import the data ... It is not just because it imports, but I need to manage an entire register in order to have access to them. Thanks again and congratulations for your patience in always having to teach!

Comment: Tanaike Unfortunately when trying to import, at some point he returns a message saying that it was unable to connect to the server, only importing part of the data.

Do you think that if I decrease the number of columns of imported data, that might solve the problem? If so, could you teach me how I can define in the script which columns I want to import? Thank you very much

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. In my environment, also I might be able to see the same issue of your situation. In this case, it is considered that all values are still not put. So how about waiting for completely putting all values? Because the CSV data is large as I said. If you want to put the specific columns to the Spreadsheet, I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? Even when you use this modification, when the number of columns is large, the same situation might occur. Please be careful this.

Comment: This is the big problem, I wait inside GAS until the notification that the script has been completed. But unfortunately he can never finish the request. It's a shame, but it's really the fault of Google Sheets and its limitations right. Unfortunately there is nothing to do. But I will decrease the number of data to be imported as you said, that at least the chance of making a mistake decreases. Thank you very much

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. the total cells of the CSV data are about 1.9 million cells. So when the specific columns are retrieved by filtering, the cost can be reduced. In the current stage, this method might be suitable for your situation.

Comment: @Frederico Mattos I proposed one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? In this case, in order to put all CSV data, Sheets API is used. If that was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: It worked perfectly on every attempt made without any kind of error. Thank you very much!